# what is the correct way to pass data to create react componment

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, reactjs

i am us asp.net before  and i will pass data in html .i always put the data in  tag and the componment require it

ex:

```
<body> 
<div id="target"></div> 
<script> 
var data="@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));" </script> 
</body>
```

JS:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
var data=window.data;
ReactDOM.render(<comp d={data}/>,document.getElementById('target') );
```

is it the correct way to pass data?
or i should use ajax to get the data?

Comment: No. Any data you need from the server should be called from React component (like with ajax) and used there. There is no point in doing it this way as it's ugly

Answer (score 0):

if you are passing data as prop to a child component you can access it by this.props.YourProp

in this example if you are passing data to your componnet as d you can access it by this.props.d

if your app is growing  you are going to need handle complex state changes.
so i suggest you to use Racket https://github.com/mohebifar/racket
and redux to handle your state changes.